# Mage Frost Talent, Frostfire Orb, what is it?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What is the Frostfire Orb? I put a talent put into it on my lvl 65 Frost Mage. I do not see a spell anywhere in my spell book related to it. How do I begin taking advantage of this talent specialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not a single point talent, it does not grant a new ability. Instead, it modifies your [Flame Orb](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=82731/flame-orb) ability to do frost damage instead and add a chill.

The [first rank](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=84726) of the talent explains this.

Answer (score 1):

Frostfire Orb modifies the [Flame Orb](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=82731#comments) spell.

The reason you do not see the ability is because it is not learned until level 81. Until that point, the talent is only useful due to the effect it has on your Frostfire bolt.